# How to use multiple graphql query hooks in single function component in react?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-hooks, react-apollo, react-functional-component

I call multiple `graphql query` using `useQuery`. And it's shows error like
 `Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.`
I know why it came but i don't know how to prevent from this error. This is `Functional components`

my code here

```
  const [categoryList, updateCategoryList] = useState([]);
  const [payeeList, updatePayeeList] = useState([]);

  if (data) {
    const categories = (data.categories as unknown) as Category[];
    if (
      !isEqual(categoryList, categories) ||
      categoryList.length !== categories.length
    ) {
      updateCategoryList([...categories]);
    }
  }

  if (isEmpty(payeeList)) {
    const { loading, data } = useQuery(payeesQuery);
    if (data) {
      const payees = (data.payees as unknown) as Payee[];
      if (!isEqual(payeeList, payees) || payeeList.length !== payees.length) {
        updateCategoryList([...payees]);
      }
    }
  }
```

Sorry guys I noob for react.

Comment: Don't call hooks inside function or conditions
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#rules-of-hooks

Comment: write this at the top of the component.

const { loading, data } = useQuery(payeesQuery);

Comment: There is only one graphql Query. right?

Comment: yeah I write top of the component and didn't use inside a function....  my question is How to use multiple graphql query hooks in single function component?

Comment: in the above code the useQuery is called from inside of  `if` condition

Comment: Does this solve your problem?

https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/3644#issuecomment-584980892

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for eg you can use like this

```
const ExampleComponent = () => {
    const { loading:payeesLoading, data:payeesData } = useQuery(payeesQuery);
    const { loading:secondLoading, data:secondData } = useQuery(secondQuery);

    useEffect(() => { //effect hook for first query

    } ,[payeesData] )

    useEffect(() => { //effect hook for second query

    } ,[secondData] )

    return (<div>
    your contents
    </div>)

}
```

like this you can write multiple querys in a single component.